# Zero Knowledge Range Proofs

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, zksnark, zero-knowledge

I am new to the world of Zero Knowledge Range Proofs. I read the following on GitHub: https://github.com/ing-bank/zkproofs

The Zero Knowledge Range Proof allows the blockchain network to validate that a secret number is within known limits without disclosing the secret number. This is useful to reach consensus in a variety of use cases:

1. Validate that someone's age is between 18 and 65 without disclosing the age.
2. Validate that someone is in Europe without disclosing the exact location.

**The Zero Knowledge Range Proof requires a commitment on a number by a trusted party (for instance a government committing on someone's age), an Ethereum user can use this commitment to generate a range proof. The Ethereum network will verify this proof.**

Any idea about the provided example that of the commitment can be verified on etherum or any link to a technical paper that describes how a user TP commit to a user age, then the blockchain can verify that commitment ?

Comment: That's a very good question. I quickly went through the paper. They talking all the time about a "commited number", but they are not explaining what it means exactly. It could be anything like a hash or a salted hash or whatever... with zokrates for instance you could have a salted hash onchain endorsed by an authority, and then you can make a zks proof that you know the salt and the age corresponding to the salted onchain hash without revealing the salt or the age itself.